# Anonymous function in function expression having name

Tags: javascript

How is that I am able to see name for anonymous function in JavaScript ?

```
var foog = function(){
    console.log("Hi");
}

console.dir(foog); // The name property shows `foog`
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this an *anonymous* function IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism is called [inferred function name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names) and was introduced in ES 2015:

> Variables and methods can infer the name of an anonymous function from its syntactic position (new in ECMAScript 2015).

```js
var foog = function(){
    console.log("Hi");
}

console.dir(foog.name);
```